# Setting height auto of textarea causes scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to design a textarea which resizes itself according to the content. This is what I wrote -

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
    <textarea data-autoresize='true'></textarea>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('body').on('keyup input','textarea', function(){
    var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;
    $(this).css('height','auto').css('height', this.scrollHeight + offset);
}).removeAttr('data-autoresize');
```

**CSS**

```
textarea {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

However, this causes the container element to scroll to the top of the textarea on each character input when the text area grows in size and the container becomes scrollable. Is there any way to stop this scroll?

**Edit**

You can refer this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/07d6gsb1/

Comment: Can you share your HTML structure as well? edit: thanks!

Comment: Why do you set the height twice?

Comment: @moopet because otherwise the offset gets **added**, even removing chars adds height, he basically resets the height on input.

Comment: I cannot seem to recreate this issue though, what browser are you using? http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/GNLmoY

Comment: That's odd, is your problem persisting inside my codepen?

Comment: Oh, is your problem that the screen jumps back to the top of the input container when there's more content below it?

Comment: @Roberrrt Yes. I will create a fiddle to show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scrolling position is automatically set to the top of the focused element (the textarea). You'll have to manually set your scrolling position to the initial value, add this to your jQuery:

```
$('body').on('keyup input','textarea', function(){
    var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;
    var scroll = $('body').scrollTop();
    $(this).css('height','auto').css('height', this.scrollHeight + offset);
    $('body').scrollTop(scroll);
}).removeAttr('data-autoresize');
```

`.scrollTop()` takes the scrolling position of an element, `scrollTop(n)` *sets* the scrolling position of an element.

A working codepen:
http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/GNLmoY

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin [autogrow](https://github.com/ro31337/jquery.ns-autogrow).

You can try by pressing and hold enter key in textarea. Compare the effect with the other auto expanding textarea plugin....

```
$(function() {
   $('textarea').autogrow();
});
```

note: you should include the needed js files...

To prevent the scrollbar in the textarea from flashing on & off during expansion/contraction, you can set the `overflow` to `hidden` as well: